# "amplify env checkout" suddenly fails with validation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

For our Web App we are using the multienv feature of amplify (version 1.8.2). We have three environments `dev`, `test` and `prod`. `dev` and `test` work as expected, but when trying to `amplify checkout env prod`, we get an error:

```
✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
2019-09-06T07:20:35.327Z - error: uncaughtException: 1 validation error detected: Value '2019/09/05/[$LATEST]f49ad3bd7fb14116990e4788bf942838' at 'stackName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*|arn:[-a-zA-Z0-9:/._+]* date=Fri Sep 06 2019 09:20:35 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), pid=43660, uid=501, gid=20, cwd=/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx, execPath=/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node, version=v12.6.0, argv=[/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node, /usr/local/bin/amplify, env, checkout, prod], rss=220467200, heapTotal=160178176, heapUsed=137182168, external=24817067, loadavg=[2.6630859375, 2.60302734375, 2.5556640625], uptime=834175, trace=[column=29, file=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js, function=Request.extractError, line=50, method=extractError, native=false, column=20, file=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js, function=Request.callListeners, line=106, method=callListeners, native=false, column=10, file=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js, function=Request.emit, line=78, method=emit, native=false, column=14, file=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js, function=Request.emit, line=683, method=emit, native=false, column=10, file=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js, function=Request.transition, line=22, method=transition, native=false, column=12, file=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js, function=AcceptorStateMachine.runTo, line=14, method=runTo, native=false, column=10, file=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js, function=null, line=26, method=null, native=false, column=9, file=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js, function=null, line=38, method=null, native=false, column=12, file=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js, function=null, line=685, method=null, native=false, column=18, file=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js, function=Request.callListeners, line=116, method=callListeners, native=false], stack=[ValidationError: 1 validation error detected: Value '2019/09/05/[$LATEST]f49ad3bd7fb14116990e4788bf942838' at 'stackName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*|arn:[-a-zA-Z0-9:/._+]*,     at Request.extractError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29),     at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20),     at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10),     at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14),     at Request.transition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10),     at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12),     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10,     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9),     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12),     at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)]
```

And `amplify status` says all the components (Auth, API ect.) need to be created, i.e. it is not initialized correctly.

I have tried to restore the environment from the cloud with `amplify env pull --restore`, but this results in the same error.

A quick search on the internet did not give me any clues. Where should I start investigating to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solved with a version update of `amplify-cli`. Noticed I am quite behind, current version is `1.12.0`.